# Separable equations question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

So I have this equation:

$$
\frac {1}{y} = \frac {d}{dx} (3y)
$$

How will I go about solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the title, use separable trick.

$$3\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{y}$$

$$3\int y dy = \int dx $$